# Logic for POST call in multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, api

I want to make a POST call from my end with

```
"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------"RANDOM_24_DIGIT_NUMBER.
```

I am unable to deduce the logic for generating the boundary and getting 400 as response.
I am utilizing JS.

The response is 200 when done via POSTMAN, however I want to achieve it within my code.
Can someone help me with the logic that POSTMAN utilizes to generate this number.

Headers when done via POSTMAN:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------237519436009365388953211
Content-Length: 2749

Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------214502465121174114780437
Content-Length: 2749
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's strange that you're getting an error.
Normally, a boundary can be almost anything (see [RFC2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)).

But you shouldn't generate a boundary manually. [Use `FormData` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).
It generates `Content-Type` automatically.
See [an example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file).

Comment: Is there any other way except FormData. Basically I want to know the algorithm utlized to generate the boundary. 
Like in this case what algorithm would POSTMAN use

Comment: Well, as per RFC2046 boundary can be anything. For instance, [FormData polyfill uses](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/blob/820421ba9ee291cbf6b1b21aaa14ae1846d7c66c/FormData.js#L343) `Math.random()`.
You should just carefully count number of dashes. Every boundary in the middle must be prefixed with two dashes. The closing boundary must be both prefixed and suffixed with two dashes. See [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1)